# Why is DataGrid Column collapsing?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a DataGrid called ChainList.xaml created in a folder called Service.

```
 <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="Column" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
          ColumnHeaderStyle="{DynamicResource MedicalHistoryTableHeader}" 
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Height="300">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Chain Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="Auto"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Cypher" Binding="{Binding Cypher}" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tags" Binding="{Binding TagList}" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Components" Binding="{Binding ComponentList}" Width="200"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Points" Binding="{Binding Points}" Width="*"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I use this DataGrid somewhere else as well, in another Xaml file.

```
 <service:ChainList DataContext="{....}" />
```

The Columns are behaving correctly in the original controller but when I embed it to another controller the columns are collapsing. 
I use * to use the remaining space of the whole DataGrid.
Did anybody bump into this problem before?

[image: Original controller]
[image: Embedded controller]

Comment: What's the "original controller"? Please provide a MCVE of your issue when asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: have you tried using a viewbox to show your control instead of a grid?

Comment: @mm8 The  Original controller is where the DataGrid is defined

Comment: What's the root element in the XAML file?

Comment: @DanieleSartori Same result. :(

Comment: Problem solved... ItemsControl :)